# Open a new window in JSF when a user checks a box?

Tags: jsf

How do I open a new window in JSF when a user checks a checkbox?  Here's what I have:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox title="shipping" value="#{ShippingStationHandler.view}" style="width: 73px; height: 29px"> </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Comment: usinf this code    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox
                    title="shipping"
                   value="#{ShippingStationHandler.view}"     style="width: 73px; height: 29px">
            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

Comment: it is completely unclear what you trying to do. I'm deleting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Very unclear but simply;

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox onclick="linkPopup(this)" />
```

and in script tags

```
    function linkPopup(obj) {

                if(obj.checked == true)
                window.open('http://stackoverflow.com' ,'Link','height=600, width=800');        
    }
```

can be useful for somebody...